# Vue js. Several classes with js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<div class="container" :class="{ qwerty: !open }" :class="lower? 'left' : 'right'">
```

Hi, why vue doesn't allow me to add several classes with conditions, like in example. 
It allows to add one only. 
How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I think for you it should be enough to do this:

```
:class="[{qwerty: !open}, lower ? 'left' : 'right']"
```

it's a mix from `passing an array of classes` and `passing objects`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax).

```
:class="[lower ? 'left' : 'right', upper ? 'up' : 'down']"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple conditions that goes too lengthy including too many logics then go with `computed`

```
<div class="container" :class="getClass">
```

then

```
computed: {
 getClass() {
  var className = 'container';
  if(!this.open) className = className+' '+'querty';

  if(this.lower) className = className+' '+'left';
  else className = className+' '+'right';

  return className;
 }
}
```